# Read data in chunks from large request_body

Tags: python-3.x, request, tornado, chunks

I am new to tornado . Currently I want to read from a post request_body . But data in post request is large so I want to implement it through stream_body_request  in Tornado. But I am not able to implement it. How to read this 'img_data' in chunks?

```
@stream_request_body
class MyReportPDF(BaseHandler):
async def post(self):
    data = escape.json_decode(self.get_body_argument('img_data'))#This data is an base_64_array
    for i in range(len(data)):
        # Clean the base_64 Image
        data[i].replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '')
        decode_image.append(base64.b64decode(data[i]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use [`@stream_request_body`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html?highlight=stream_request_body#tornado.web.stream_request_body), your RequestHandler class should define a method `data_received` which will be called with data as it comes in. The `post` method is called at the end after all of the data is received.

Note that it is not currently possible to use the argument-related methods with `@stream_request_body`; you'll need to parse the data in `data_received` as it comes in. This means that if possible you'll want to structure your API to receive the image as a plain HTTP PUT instead of being wrapped in a form-style POST.